# Elastic Stack causing Read-Only disk issue

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, filesystems, elastic-stack, elk

I'm using Elastic Stack for some log analysis, and I have a deployed cluster using Stack V7.16.1 on Linux platform (ubuntu), but what is happening is that every time one of the partitions mapped to path.data is becoming Read-Only until I run file-system check (fsck) on the disk and repair the errors and restart the service.
Is this a common issue in Elastic Stack?? If anyone had the same issue please let me know ?
and is there any fix to this situation.

Thank You